# Eigenvectors from different eigenspaces of an operator are orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a vector space with an inner product on $\mathbb C$ with a finite dimension, and $T : V \to V$ an operator (not necessarily Normal,) with eigenvectors $\{v_1,...,v_k\}$ for different eigenvalues $\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k\}$. Are $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k\}$ necessarily an orthotognal set of vectors?

Comment: What did you try? However the answer is, in general, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you really need normality. Consider, for instance, the matrix
$$
 A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix};
$$
viewed as a linear operator on $\mathbb{C}^2$ with the standard inner product, $A$ is not normal. Then for
$$
 v_1 := \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad v_2 := \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -2 \end{pmatrix},
$$
$Av_1 = v_1$, $Av_2 = -v_2$, but $\langle v_1, v_2 \rangle = 1 \neq 0$.